# Intellij compare two coverage data

Tags: java, testing, intellij-idea, code-coverage

I have have two java testcases which test very similar functionality. With IntelliJ's coverage report it is possible two see the source code coverage of each test.

Now I want to see the difference between both tests. Example

```
void foo(a) {
if (a>4) { print("hu"); }}
```

Testcase 1:

```
  foo(1);
```

Testcase 2:

```
  foo(5);
```

Now I want IntelliJ to tell me that 'print("hu")' is called only by testcase1. How do I achive that?

Comment: Manual workaround looks like: Exporting coverage result to html and compare each package step by step in browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can find caller of the method

```
StackTraceElement[] stackTraceElements = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
```

This `StackTraceElement` has `getClassName()`, and `getMethodName()` witch help you to find caller.

Ex:

```
public class A {
public void foo(int a) {
    if (a > 4) {
        System.out.println("hu");
        StackTraceElement[] stackTraceElements = Thread.currentThread()
                                                                .getStackTrace();
        System.out.println(stackTraceElements[2].getMethodName());
      }
   }
```

.

```
class Result {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    methodA();
}

public static void methodA(){
    new A().foo(5);
}

public static void methodB(){
    new A().foo(2);
 }
 }
}
```

Out put:

```
 hu
 methodA
```

Comment: Nice idea but does not solve my problem. Maybe both tests call the same method (which would mean that there is no difference) but I need to know whether the path execution (including all if-branches) differs.

Comment: @EhmKa take a look at my example. It is working fine and you can use this for your need. Now you can say your method calling from `methodA`

Comment: @Rucheria My problem is that I do not know the differents execution paths. Therefore I can not put your given example into each possible execution path, because there are to many.